# I need help uploading files with a time delay

Tags: python

Hi can someone please help with with this. I wrote a code that moves files from folder to folder. The problem is that code moves all of them at the same time all at once.

I need a file to be moved then there is a delay then it will move the next file. I've been trying this all day and I can't figure it out.

```
import os
import shutil
import time

source_dir = 'C:/Users/bigwi/Desktop/Upload'
target_dir = 'C:/Users/bigwi/Dropbox/ytbin'

file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

time.sleep(15)

for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```

this is what I'm working with so far I just need to figure out how to move one file at a time so I can use a time delay so it moves one file then waits 10 seconds then moves another file...

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Include ```time.sleep``` in the loop

Comment: @ThierryLathuille they mean that the files are moved really quickly and they want a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Simple; add a time delay in the `for` loop.

```
for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
    time.sleep(10) # replace 10 with however long you want your delay to be
```

Comment: thank you thank u are the best, sorrry  i just got into all this and literly this is my first code i did on my own i dont even know how any of it works but i mode the time.sleep down under the FOR part and it worked!!!! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
import os , time , shutil
source_dir = 'C:/Users/bigwi/Desktop/Upload'
target_dir = 'C:/Users/bigwi/Dropbox/ytbin'
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
    time.sleep(15)
```

`time.sleep(15)` should be inside the `for-loop`.